# How do i fix "InnoDB Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic Error"

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, innodb

i am running a Nextcloud Server on a Ubuntu 20.04 which was running fine. I wanted to upgrade the Nextcloud Version and make a backup before. This is what i did:

1. plugged in a external harddrive (/dev/sdb)
2. executed "sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb" to make a copy of the entire harddrive
3. left it to run overnight, the next morning it was completed successfuly
4. next day, i put the nextcloud out of maintenance mode and rebooted the entire server
5. MySQL does not start anymore.

systemctl status mysql.service gives this output:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Tue 2023-11-07 09:31:10 CET; 989ms ago
    Process: 11409 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 11417 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 9244)
     Memory: 243.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─11417 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

The /var/log/mysql error.log contains this:

```
2023-11-07T06:58:13.444740Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2023-11-07T06:58:14.111726Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 1485
2023-11-07T06:58:14.133488Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-11-07T06:58:20.046018Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013895] [InnoDB] Found redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo70356 which has format (v0) and is stored inside #innodb_redo.
2023-11-07T06:58:20.046045Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-11-07T06:58:20.439303Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-11-07T06:58:20.439722Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-11-07T06:58:20.439778Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-11-07T06:58:20.441103Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2023-11-07T06:58:21.122634Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 1646
2023-11-07T06:58:21.131645Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-11-07T06:58:25.012944Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013895] [InnoDB] Found redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo70356 which has format (v0) and is stored inside #innodb_redo.
2023-11-07T06:58:25.012978Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-11-07T06:58:25.407755Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-11-07T06:58:25.408120Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-11-07T06:58:25.408177Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-11-07T06:58:25.409555Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2023-11-07T06:58:26.122984Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 1669
2023-11-07T06:58:26.129932Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-11-07T06:58:30.092052Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013895] [InnoDB] Found redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo70356 which has format (v0) and is stored inside #innodb_redo.
2023-11-07T06:58:30.092088Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-11-07T06:58:30.486290Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-11-07T06:58:30.486691Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-11-07T06:58:30.486746Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

i've given the mysql-user permissions for /var/lib/mysql folder. several restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Alright i feel like an absolute idiot right now, but maybe someone stumbles upon the same Issue in the Future:

the external drive was still plugged in and when i started the server it somehow booted from the external drive, which led to the error.